# Media query in CSS is not appearing in webpage

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I am working on a media query example in my boot camp. My media query does not seem to function on my page. Can anyone tell me why? I have reviewed it with my classmates, and after thirty minutes of review we have not been able to find the answer after looking at examples online. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```css
body {
    background-color: lightblue;
text-align: center;
list-style-position: inside;
}

.banana {
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
}

.thick-white-border {
    border-color: white;
    border-width: 15px;
    border-style: double;
}

.smaller-image {
    width: 300px;
    height: 600px;
    border-radius: 55px;
}
.green-background {
    background-color: green;
}

h1 {
    font-family: 'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

h2 {
    font-family: fantasy;
}

ul {
    font-family: Impact, Haettenschweiler, 'Arial Narrow Bold', sans-serif;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 400px) {
    ul { color: green; }  /* show it on small screens */
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/index.css">
    <title>About Me 02</title>
</head>
<body>
    <H1 class="font-family">I am Lashonda Miller</H1>
    <img src="./bananaGirl.jpg" alt="This is my selfie" class="thick-white-border smaller-image ">
    <H2 class="font-family">This is me, inside of a banana.</H2>
    <ul class="font-family">
        <li>I am 17 years old, and I've just graduated high school</li>
        <li>I'm also a certified Medical Assistent and an EKG Technician</li>
        <li>I've been to LA before, it's a cool city, very slow traffic</li>
        <li>My favorit food to eat it crab legs</li>
        <li>I love scary movies</li>
        <li>I also think everyone should go to Cedar Point</li>
        <li>I also like pumpkin seeds</li>

    </ul>
    <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/lashonda-miller-91723b1b1?lipi=urn%3Ali%3Apage%3Ad_flagship3_profile_view_base_contact_details%3B37AWsTN%2BQJ%2BVJr7bGFE%2F2A%3D%3D" target="_blank" alt="This is my linkedin profile">Come check my linkedin account
    </a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It works fine when I test it in the live demo in your page

Comment: It works perfectly fine https://i.imgur.com/Z9E2FGn.png

Comment: It works for me as well. Are you using it on chrome or a different browser when testing? You might need to add some prefixes.

Comment: You really do not need to specify the min width

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like your media query was set up for small devices, you could try increasing the max-width to 800px or more `@media screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 800px) { ul { color: green; }  }`